# Did every version of Lotus Notes include a function allowing users to export data into Excel or CSV format?

Tags: excel, csv, lotus-notes

I am trying to obtain data from the operator of a large Lotus Notes database. This operator claims that exporting the data I seek will require 300-plus hours of coding, which does not seem reasonable to me, although I am not a Lotus Notes expert. Can someone please outline for me the steps necessary to (1) select certain fields for export and then (2) export said fields into Excel or CSV format? Said database contains several different kinds of documents, if that matters.

Comment: Be careful of the way you ask for it.  If you ask for a general purpose tool that you can point at any database, with any design, select any group of documents, specify any group of fields, in any specific order, and export them... that will be a significant amount of programming. But if you ask for a tool that works for a specific database design, the documents in a specific view or folder, a specific set of fields, in a specific order, and exports them, then it's a very straightforwarde task. Of course, there are degrees of difficulty in between as well.

Answer (score 0):

A developer would have multiple ways to do what you request:
The easiest thing would be to create a so called "view" in the database you want to export, that contains all fields needed. Then an export to csv is just a fiew clicks away.
The efford would be less than 2hours, even forma beginner in Lotus Notes. Usually I would estimate 15 minutes per view. If you have multiple document types to export, then multiply this value with the number of types.

Of course there are many examples out there to use a configurable export, so that you do not have to create views for exporting. Writing such a solution from scratch would need about 8-16 hours for an experienced LotusScript Developer.

The advantage of such a solution would be, that the code does not have to be in the database to export (if you do not have designer access to the database).

If the database is closed source, then one would have to reverse engeneer the fieldnames. That could last a little longer, but is not impossible.

However: 300 hours of coding is definitely to much. Even in worst case, an export to csv should never take longer than 30hours, and then you have something like the "swiss army knife" of exporting, fully configurable, flexible, and usable for any database that is out there...

Answer (score 0):

As Thorsten and Richard already said, to create a one-time export of a specific database, it should not be very hard for a competent Notes developer. I would agree with Torsten than 30 hours is sufficient to create a generic export utility.
As a matter of fact, I created one to export Notes documents as XML, and it should be fairly trivial to modify it to export as CSV.
You can find out more about my tool at http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter

Here is a screenshot of the utility:

[image: Screenshot of XML Exporter for Lotus Notes]